# Mutation token all way return a null Graphql

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

I try to create a token using JWT and a GraphQL server

[image]

I just have this resolver.
[image]

But when I try to do the consults:

```
mutation authenticatedUser($input:authenticatedUserInput){
    authenticatedUser(input:$input){
      token
    }
    
  }
```

I just get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "authenticatedUser": {
      "token": null
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I am using the server:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
})
```

What I am doing wrong here? I am new to GraphQL. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I go deep in apollo documentation and I have to return something like this.

```
authenticatedUser: (_, { input }) => {
      const {email} = input;
      const token = jwt.sign({ email }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn:'24h' });
      return {token}
    }
  },
```

no like

```
return token
```